# Can you develop an app for the Microsoft band, without a corresponding mobile app always being connected?

Tags: microsoft-band

I have several Microsoft bands, to be used as part of a group health initiative. I intend to develop a single app on a tablet which will pull the data from the bands. This will be a manual process, there will not be a constant connection to the tablet and no connection to Microsoft Health.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks
Emma

Comment: Can you be more specific about the kind of data you intend to use from the Band?

Comment: @PhilHoff--MSFT I am not OP but I have a similar question. Is it posible to buffer any data in the band itself? How does the exercise tile sync the data when then phone is not close? (I have seen this when I left my phone in my car by mistake) I am interested in buffering the gyroscope and accelerometer data.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is no: Historical sensor values are not stored or buffered on the Band itself.

It does however depend on what sensors you are interested in. The sensor values are not buffered, so you can only read the current (realtime) value of the sensors. 
But sensors such as pedometer and distance are incrementing over time, so these values will make sense even though you are only connected once in a while. Whereas for, e.g., the heart rate and skin temperature, you will only get the current (realtime) value.

So it depends on your use case.

Comment: It would be heart rate, distance, time of exercise etc. So if the band can't establish a connection to a device at the time of exercise, it just doesn't record anything? From what I have read it has quite a decent internal memory, is this just for system data? Thanks